# Порядок выдачи из MySQL

Tags: sql

Табличка `Категория` связана с табличкой `Товар` (один ко многим).
Можно ли настраивать порядок выдачи товаров не добавляя дополнительного поля (например поле `rate` и потом `order by rate`)?

Поясню, почему не нравится добавлять ещё одно поле: если у нас уже есть 100 товаров с `rate` от 1 до 100, если нужно добавить товар ровно в середину - нужно переписать `rate` у половины товаров.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чудес не бывает. order by надо указать какое то поле. Так что без него никак. Но ни кто не заставляет нумеровать 1,2,3... . Вы можете нумеровать изначально например 1,101,201... и при вставке в середину записи искать среднее значение. т.е. при ставке после 2й записи давать 150.

Мало 100, сделайте 10000 начальный шаг, например. В любом случае надо будет предусмотреть процедуру полной перенумерции таблицы, которую запускать в случае если зазора для новой записи все таки не осталось. Но с шагом 10k ее запуск будет необходим очень редко.

Т.е. алгоритм выдачи нового rate таков:

- Если добавляется запись после последней существующей - берем rate последней записи +10000
- В любом другом случае берем среднее арифметическое между rate записей *до* и *после*
- Если все таки места нет - запускаем перенумерацию
- При удалении записи с какой то позиции rate других записей вообще не меняем

Кстати, перенумерация выполняется одним запросом (Пример для MySQL):

```
update table set rate=(select @i:=@i+10000)
 where (select @i:=1)=1
 order by rate
```

Перенумерация для postgresql:

```
update table O
   set rate=N.new
  from (
    select id, (row_number() over(order by rate))*10000 new
      from table
  ) N
  where N.id=O.id
```

В случае, если нужна нумерация в пределах каких либо групп добавить `partition by` в фразу `over()`

Comment: зачем ему "в середину" товар добавлять? ну просто в  business domain логике, чего он добиться хочет?

Comment: @strangeqargo Он спросил "_Можно ли настраивать_" - значит его пользователю надо иметь возможность самому решать на каком месте сортировки должен быть товар. Такое требование достаточно часто встречается

Comment: я вижу в этом какое-то извращение.

Comment: @strangeqargo Ну это вы какому нибудь маркетологу скажите, который решает, что какой то товар залежался и надо бы его продвинуть, показав на первых позициях

Comment: дать ему топовый rate что мешает? не 100, а 101?

Comment: @strangeqargo А кто сказал, что маркетолог решит показать товар именно первым. На первых местах он может быть какой то бренд держит, с которым у них есть договор об этом. А вот после него уже помещает то что еще надо двигать

Comment: на сайте-то порядок выдачи все-равно ограничен, почему нельзя в алогоритме решать (как баннеры в рекламных системах выдаются). оч странный вопрос и решение, простите. потом может быть пойму эту логику

Comment: @strangeqargo Кстати, в вопросе нигде не сказано, что это для сайта. (Мне в принципе то же так кажется, но вот ориентироваться на это я бы не стал). Может это вообще для какой нибудь выходной формы в НЕ web системе, для начальства, которое хочет отдельные позиции сразу видеть :) В алгоритме наверняка можно. Но заказчикам получающим продукт это не всегда удобно. Может они хотят сами, без вмешательства программера.

Comment: @strangeqargo тут примеров много, не только категория-товар. 
Например, если дать пользователю сортировать "друзей" в контакт-листе, или какие то медиа-файлы в его личной медиатеке. 
В любом случае ответ Mike мне достаточен.