# Вставить и подвинуть id

Tags: mysql

Есть возможность вставить в середину таблицы строку и подвинуть id?

Таблица:

```
id | val
--------
1  | value 1
--------
2  | value 2
--------
3  | value 3
```

После вставки (id 2, value 4):

```
id | val
--------
1  | value 1
--------
2  | value 4
--------
3  | value 2
--------
4  | value 3
```

Comment: Смотря какое количество данных и какие способы доступны, способы есть. Нужно больше конкретики, чем и при каких обстоятельствах вы хотите это сделать.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь запросами и сам знаю можно, интересует есть ли один конкретный запрос чтоб не мудрить велосипеды

Comment: Возможность то есть, только во первых за две операции, во вторых id должно быть не autoincrement, в третьих - это очень тяжелая операция т.к. может менять почти все записи в таблице и в четвертых, самое главное, это в реляционных БД практически никогда делать не нужно. А если все таки очень хочется то напишите для чего это, наверняка существуют более практичные решения проблемы, чем перенумерация id

Comment: @Mike конечно autoincrement, не думал что перенумерация id такая критическая и нежелательная задача

Comment: Автоинкремент поля вообще менять нельзя. Придется вести id другими методами. Вот вы вставляете вторую запись, а за ней их еще 10к например. Как думаете сколько времени будет идти изменение 9998 записей ? И вообще ID по возможности никогда не должны меняться, на то они и ID. Вдруг на эту таблицу у вас другие еще ссылаются

Comment: @Mike записей будет не более 10, не ссылаются

Comment: Вот тут для сортировки хтели перенумерацию. Запрос в конце можно использовать, но понятное дело не автоматом при вставке, а только отдельным запросом. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/545763/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8-mysql/545766#545766