# Чем руководствоваться при назначении индексов и первичных ключей

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Здравствуйте. Я никак не могу понять на какие колонки в базе нужно ставить индексы. Читал про них: написано, что надо ставить на то поле, куда идет запрос `where`.

Первый вопрос. Допустим, у меня запрос идет на поле `name`, и на это же поле я ставлю индекс. Но, если я в будущем захочу что бы запрос шел на поле `slug`, то как тут быть? Тоже ставить индекс на него, и получится 2 индекса?

Второй вопрос. Как правильно сделать поле в бд, для своей сортировки ресурсов? Например поле `sort-order`, и сделать его primary key?

Comment: Ну тут вопрос как часто происходит поиск. он может и без индекса отлично отработать, но медленнее, чем с индексом. С другой стороны индекс замедляет вставку новых записей. Если понимаете, что запросы по name постоянно идут и других полей в этом запросе не используется то делаете индекс. А что до некого поля для сортировки - его primary key точно делать не стоит. Правильный первичный ключ никогда не меняется за все время жизни записи. А сортировку наверняка захочется изменять

Comment: Получается можно обойтись и без индексов? Я наверное не правильно обьяснил про `sort_order`. Допустим у меня есть 5 категорий. Я добавляю 6 категорию. И надо что бы у этой новой категории автоматом поле `sort_order` стало 6 (я ведь не буду вспоминать или лезть в базу и смотреть у какой же категории циферка 5 и есть ли она вообще). Это для того что бы на фронте упорядочить категории так как мне удобно. Как в prestashop и opencart это сделано?)

Comment: Да, можно без индексов. Просто поиск без индекса идет полным перебором таблицы. Если в ней пара тысяч записей - это куда не шло. А искать в таблице пару строк из миллиона полным перебором уже накладно. Ну вести сортировку в таком случае ручками придется, чудес не бывает. Но можно оставить ее NULL пока пользователь не определиться. И сортировать по sord_order и id. А id растут обычно в порядке добавления записей, если они автоинкремент сделаны.

Comment: А возможно sort_order тоже авто инкремент сделать? Что б тоже расло в порядке возрастания? Я имею ввиду не будит ли это нарушением правил?

Comment: автоинкремент поле нельзя менять руками

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо за разъяснение

Comment: Вот кстати пример как можно делать сортировку http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/545763/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8-mysql/545766#545766

Comment: Попробую так. Спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

1) Можно сделать составной индекс.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD INDEX name_slug_idx (name, slug)
```

2) Позже добавить индекс на поле `slug` через `ALTER TABLE`:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD INDEX slug_idx (slug)
```

---

Сортировка производится не добавлением нового поля, а при выполнении SQL-запроса:

```
SELECT slug FROM tbl WHERE name = 'hello' ORDER BY field DESC
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. С индексами ясно, а сортировка, я не это имел ввиду. В коменте под вопросом написал что имел ввиду

Comment: @Mike исправил, спасибо.