# MySQL: добавить новую запись в таблицу с обновлением значений существующих записей

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте!

Есть массив картинок

```
$usr_imgs = array('1.jpg','3.jpg','8.jpg','9.jpg','11.jpg');
```

Массив добавлен в таблицу, ключами которого является поле ord, а значения - photo_name:

```
+----+------------+-----+
| id | photo_name | ord |
+----+------------+-----+
| 13 | 1.jpg      |   0 |
| 14 | 3.jpg      |   1 |
| 15 | 8.jpg      |   2 |
| 16 | 9.jpg      |   3 |
| 17 | 11.jpg     |   4 |
+----+------------+-----+
```

В массиве $usr_imgs пользователь добавил ещё одну картинку, например '5.jpg'. Массив теперь имеет следующий вид:

```
$usr_imgs = array('1.jpg','3.jpg','5.jpg' ,'8.jpg','9.jpg','11.jpg');
```

Вопрос заключается в том, **как можно одним запросом MySQL** перезаписать ключи для значений, которые уже существуют в таблице? (или одним не получится?)

А новую картинку **5.jpg** добавить как новую запись с соответствующим ключом.
Т.е. чтобы получилась такая таблица:

```
+----+------------+-----+
| id | photo_name | ord |
+----+------------+-----+
| 13 | 1.jpg      |   0 |
| 14 | 3.jpg      |   1 |
| 15 | 8.jpg      |   3 |
| 16 | 9.jpg      |   4 |
| 17 | 11.jpg     |   5 |
| 18 | 5.jpg      |   2 |
+----+------------+-----+
```

Comment: Это же неудобно, каждый раз переписывать все записи ... http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/545763/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8-mysql/545766#545766

Comment: А в вашем случае простой `update ord=ord+1 where ord>=2` поможет

Comment: @Mike я читал про on duplicate key update, но не совсем понял как его  использовать

Comment: А причем тут on duplicate. он не поможет. Одним запросом вставить одну запись и обновить другие в MySQL совершенно невозможно

Comment: Или вы хотите одним запросом вставить сразу все записи из массива и при этом обновить ключи у существующих ... но если в массиве вообще не окажется какой то картинки (ее удалили) то удаление надо будет проводить отдельным запросом

Comment: Если так, то да. делаете photo_name уникальным ключом и делаете что то типа `insert into tab(name, ord) values('1.jpg',0),('3.jpg',1) on duplicate key update set ord=value(ord)`

Comment: @Mike, Да, я хочу вставить все записи из массива, обновив ключи у существующих. Но, если в массиве оказалась картинка, которой нет  в таблице, то тогда вставить ее!

Comment: @Mike Спасибо!!