# UPDATE и ORDER BY? Что неправильно?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть вот такой запрос:

```
UPDATE hikashop_product a 
JOIN hikashop_product_category b 
ON a.product_id=b.product_id 
JOIN hikashop_category c ON c.category_id=b.category_id    
SET a.product_canonical=CONCAT(c.category_canonical,"/",a.product_id,"-",a.product_alias) 
ORDER BY  product_category_id DESC;
```

Он работает, но если добавить сортировку - то выдает ошибку:

> Ответ MySQL: #1221 - Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY

Как мне поступить? Как правильно написать?

Comment: For the multiple-table syntax, UPDATE updates rows in each table named in table_references that satisfy the conditions. Each matching row is updated once, even if it matches the conditions multiple times. For multiple-table syntax, ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used. ....... нужно переделать на выборку с `SELECT` ......... кстати `product_category_id` к какой таблице относится?

Comment: каким образом это можно сделать в моем случае?

Comment: Если таблицы связаны 1:1 - какой смысл в сортировке? А если 1:N - то это вообще лотерея, а не обновление...

Comment: Для того чтобы это не было лотереей и нужна сортировка. Останется только последнее значение.

Comment: Вам order не поможет. update _никогда_ не меняет одну и ту же строку дважды, так что понятия "последнее значение" не существует. Вам надо переписать запрос так, что бы для каждой обновляемой строки он заведомо выдавал одно единственное, верное, значение. т.е. выносите все,, что джоинете в подзапрос и там выполняйте группировку и получайте min/max или как то еще вычисляйте какое из значений оставить

Comment: оформите свой комментарий как ответ. Я думаю его надо принять

Answer (score -1):

Нельзя использовать ORDER BY в конструкции UPDATE

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: Ответ правильный, но для конкретного ответа не помешало бы добавить больше информации - выдержку из документации или пару предложений о смысле сортировки при обновлении данных. Воспользуйтесь кнопкой "править".

Comment: Как это нельзя ... Документация говорит обратное: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html. Все зависит от того ради чего его применяют, вот живой пример, когда он нужен и работает: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/545763/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8-mysql/545766#545766

Comment: Почему вы не упоминаете - multitable?