# Настраиваемый порядок вывода из mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица в MySQL с полями `id(int,autoincrement), [много не относящихся к вопросу полей], pos(int)`.

Столбец pos всегда целое число по порядку 1,2,3.... По нему делается `ORDER by pos` и записи выводятся в нужном порядке. Необходимо реализовать настраиваемый порядок вывода записей.

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как реализовать 3 вещи:

1. создание записи и помещение ее в позицию m `$db->create($pos_m)`
2. перемещение записи по id из позиции m в n (старую позицию я знаю при запросе изначально) `$db->move($id, $pos_n, $pos_m)`
3. удаление записи по `id db->remove($id)`

При этих действиях нужно, чтобы pos у всех остальных записей пересчитывался по порядку заново, чтобы не было разрывов. Если запись помещается в середину, все, что больше сдвигались на +1 и т.д. Pos всегда должен отражать реальный номер по порядку, а не как предложили делать [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/545763).

Записей таких не будет много, и такие действия не будут происходить часто, поэтому здесь не нужна производительность.

Если есть возможность реализовать это на чистом SQL, здорово, но можно переложить часть работы на PHP и сделать несколько запросов.

Comment: 1. При заданном *m* получайте все записи, у которых *pos>=m*, и увиличивайте его на 1. 2. Две записи меняются местами? Тогда старую позицию сохраняйте в переменную, чтобы не потерять ее при запросах. 3. Тут вообще все просто *DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `id`={$id}*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Вставка

   ```
   INSERT INTO mytable (pos) VALUES (:pos);
   UPDATE mytable SET
     pos = pos + 1
   WHERE
     pos => :pos AND
     id <> LAST_INSERT_ID();
   ```
2. Перенос

   ```
   UPDATE mytable SET
     pos = pos + IF(:old_pos < :new_pos, -1, 1)
   WHERE
     pos BETWEEN :old_pos + 1 AND :new_pos OR
     pos BETWEEN :new_pos AND :old_pos - 1
   UPDATE mytable SET
     pos = :new_pos
   WHERE
     id = :id;
   ```
3. Необходимость пересчитывать `pos` при удалении для меня под вопросом. Разрывы на сортировку не влияют. Но если нужно, то делается так

   ```
   UPDATE mytable SET
     pos = pos - 1
   WHERE
     pos > (SELECT pos FROM mytable WHERE id = :id);
   DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id = :id;
   ```

Все мои манипуляции подразумевают, что для поля `pos` не создан уникальный ключ

Comment: Огромное спасибо за пример! Все получилось, но: в переносе у вас учитывается только ситуация, когда новая позиция ближе к началу `new_pos < old_pos`. А если я хочу перенести ближе к концу `new_pos > old_pos`, то надо сделать так `UPDATE mytable SET pos = pos + 1 WHERE pos BETWEEN :new_pos AND :old_pos - 1`. И еще при вставке полагаю имелось ввиду `pos >= :pos AND`

Comment: @Talleyran По поводу обновления Вы почти правы. Я учитывал только один вариант, когда `new_pos > old_pos`. Я дополнил ответ для второго  варианта. Ваше замечание по поводу вставки я не понял