# Кастомная сортировка неограниченного множества элементов хранящихся в базе

Tags: mysql, база-данных, сортировка, оптимизация

Всем привет. 
Столкнулся с задачей - существует множество объектов, хранящихся в таблице базы, которые пользователь может создавать в неограниченном количестве. Помимо этого, пользователь может назначить им кастомную сортировку, "перетягивая" элементы. Эта сортировка должна сохраниться и объекты должны выбираться в соответствии с ней до тех пор, пока пользователь вновь её не поменяет.

Раньше количество объектов было ограничено, и, для этих целей, существовала колонка "sort", в которую записывалось число и выборки из базы шли с сортировкой по этой колонке. Главная проблема - изменение сортировки, т.к. приходилось обновлять все записи в базе (т.е. если я хочу, чтобы 4 объект стал 8, нужно обновить записи об объектах 5-8, уменьшив их сортировку на 1, а объекту 4 проставить сортировку 8). Мягко говоря не самый оптимальный вариант, но с ограниченным кол-вом было терпимо.

Сейчас по бизнес-логике, нужно убрать ограничение. Соответственно, теоретически возможен кейс, когда пользователь захочет сделать 4 объект 100000ым и системе придется сделать 99997 апдейтов.

Пока не придумал ничего лучше, чем создать отдельную таблицу, где будет хранится user_id и sort. В sort хранить json-массив, состоящий из правильно отсортированных id элементов. Таким образом, при запросе объектов из базы - сперва запрашивается их сортировка. Потом, в соответствии с ней уже сами элементы по id'шникам. При изменении сортировки - только один запрос на апдейт.

Из плюсов вижу - можно отказаться от использования лимитов и офсетов в запросах к базе (у меня есть все id элементов в виде массива и выборка пойдет просто по pk)

Из минусов - теоретически огромный массив, который может не влезть в колонку базы (на практике, конечно, такое кол-во объектов пользователь не создаст никогда - думаю, на самом деле, объектов у самых активных пользователей будет не больше нескольких сотен). А так же, целостность данных придется поддерживать на уровне приложения, а не на уровне mysql (при удалении объекта, самому апдейтить сортировку, вычищая оттуда удаленный id).

Может быть, кто-нибудь сможет подсказать лучшее решение. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Что оптимизируем - хранение порядка, корректировку порядка, или сортировку по нему?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Порядок выдачи из MySQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/545763/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-mysql)

Comment: Сортировку и корректировку. Хранение менее критично в данном случае.

Comment: @Denis А тот ответ, что по ссылке выше не подошел ? Я боюсь другого пути нет ...