# Красивый вариант изменения порядка сортировки sql

Tags: sql

Нужно создать метод, который будет принимать item_id, sort. Назначать текущему item этот sort. А item у которых sort>=:sort делать sort + 1. Сдвигать позицию на единицу.

Самый простой вариант это через цикл. Но можно ли как-то это сделать только на sql. sort=sort+1 WHERE sort>=:sort AND item_id<>:item_id не подходит, так как в таком случае значения sort будут бесконечно расти. А нужно расти по порядку от предоставленного значения sort. Спасибо.

mysql

```
tbl products

prod_id = 1 sort = 2
prod_id = 2 sort = 3
prod_id = 3 sort = 1

плохой вариант 

    func sort($prod_id, $sort){

        UPDATE products SET sort=$sort WHERE prod_id=$prod_id

        $prods = SELECT prod_id FROM products WHERE sort>=$sort

        foreach($prods as $prod){
            $sort++
            UPDATE products SET sort=$sort WHERE prod_id=$prod->prod_id
        }

    }
```

Comment: 1) какой именно SQL сервер у вас?. 2) Несовсем понятен вопрос, добавьте пример входных и выходных данных. в MySQL например можно оперировать переменной прямо в запросе в том числе на основании данных полученных в прошлой итерации запроса.

Comment: Подскажите, как оперировать данными из предыдущей итерации mysql?

Comment: Пример update можете взять отсюда https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/545766/194569. И заодно еще несколько идей, потому что перенумерация подряд не очень эффективна, а задача судя по всему у вас примерно такая, как описано в том вопросе

Comment: @VasyaPupkin зависит от версии SQL, В общем случае объявите переменную в запросе и обновляйте ее после выполнения нужных значений, например если вы хотите получить предыдущий ID, и текущий ID в запросе, можно сделать так: `Select Id,@myId,@myId=id from sometable,@myId=0`;
Тогда на каждой итерации вы будете получать текущий Id и предыдущий ID

Comment: *sort=sort+1 WHERE sort>=:sort AND item_id<>:item_id не подходит, так как в таком случае значения sort будут бесконечно расти.* Ерунду говорите. В одном запросе на обновление каждая запись обновляется только один раз - даже если она соответствует нескольким "итерациям".