# postgresql инкремент переменной и подстановка ее в поле при update

Tags: postgresql

мне необходимо сделать update полей таблицы и подставить в значение инкрементируемое значение переменной, а именно

```
DECLARE counter int2 = 0;
BEGIN
UPDATE table SET field1 = counter++ (не работает, взял для наглядности) WHERE field2 IN (1,2,3,45,56,76)
```

подскажите плиз, как это в PostgreSQL синтаксически делается

спасибо

P.S. я знаю про field1 = field1 + 1, задача именно вышеописаная

Comment: update с join c подзапросом и вычисление порядкового номера с помощью row_number(). примерно как тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/545766/194569 в запросе для перенумерации

Comment: Огромное спасибо, изучу