# Как в таблице переназначить все id

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица post, как мне в этой таблице переназначить все id к записям, но что бы новые Id начинались с нужного числа, например с 1221 и далее по возростанию.

Comment: Запрос для перенумерации можете взять отсюда https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/545766/194569 Но замечу, что раз появилось такое желание, то видимо вы пытаетесь решить какую то другую задачу не с той стороны

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас phpmyadmin, то зайдите в нужную базу данных, потом выберите таблицу и в верхней панели найдите кнопку "Операции" и нажмите на нее. Далее найдите "AUTO_INCREMENT" и рядом с ним поставьте нужное вам значение

Comment: (из очереди проверок) Это не комментарий, а вполне себе ответ, хотя и на половину вопроса (не про перенумерацию, а про изменение счётчика) и только специфичным образом (более универсально -- привести sql-код на изменение значения автоинкремента)